# Scrapy Custom Project Command: "ImportError: No module named commands"

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to make a Scrapy custom project command to run spiders. I found [Register commands via setup.py entry points](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/commands.html?highlight=commands_module#register-commands-via-setup-py-entry-points) and did the following:

1. `mkdir commands`
2. `cd commands`
3. Created the command file `crawlall.py`:

   ```
   from scrapy.commands import ScrapyCommand
   from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
   from scrapy.crawler import Crawler

   class Command(ScrapyCommand):

       requires_project = True

       def syntax(self):
           return '[options]'

       def short_desc(self):
           return 'Runs all of the spiders'

       def run(self, args, opts):
           settings = get_project_settings()

           for spider_name in self.crawler.spiders.list():
               crawler = Crawler(settings)
               crawler.configure()
               spider = crawler.spiders.create(spider_name)
               crawler.crawl(spider)
               crawler.start()

           self.crawler.start()
   ```
4. Added `COMMANDS_MODULE = 'myprojectname.commands'` to the `settings.py`.
5. Created the `setup.py`:

   ```
   from setuptools import setup, find_packages

   setup(name='scrapy-mymodule',
     entry_points={
       'scrapy.commands': [
         'crawlall=cnblogs.commands:crawlall',
       ],
     },
    )
   ```
6. Ran the project command with `scrapy crawlall`, which threw the following error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
       load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.0rc2', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
       cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 50, in _get_commands_dict
       cmds.update(_get_commands_from_module(cmds_module, inproject))
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
       for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
       for module in walk_modules(module_name):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc2-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 63, in walk_modules
       mod = import_module(path)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
       __import__(name)
   ImportError: No module named commands
   ```

What should I do? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a module detectable, add a `__init__.py` file in the `commands` directory:

```
> pwd                # make sure that you are in commands directory
.../commands/

> touch __init__.py  # create __init__.py
```

See more info in another SO thread: [What is `__init__.py` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Yes, create **__init__.py** file inside the commands directory. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A directory with a Python script does not an importable module maketh: you need to add an `__init__.py` file to the `commands` directory as [Python documentation on modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) explains:

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages....

The `__init__.py` file can be empty.

Also, `commands` needs to be in a directory on `sys.path` if it is not already for Python to find it, as the aforementioned documentation further explains:

> When importing [a] package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.

The following Python snippet will display your `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Lastly, read a [particularly relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/1810429) in the thread to which Jon referred you for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation says [[1](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#register-commands-via-setup-py-entry-points)] that you have write the full path to your command class:

```
setup(name='scrapy-mymodule',
  entry_points={
    'scrapy.commands': [
      'crawlall=cnblogs.commands.crawlall:Command',
    ],
  },
 )
```

where:

- `Command`: Your *command* class -> `Command(ScrapyCommand):`
- `crawlall`: Your *.py file where the command class is.

> You can also add Scrapy commands from an external library by adding a
>   scrapy.commands section in the entry points of the library setup.py
>   file.
>
> The following example adds my_command command:
>       from setuptools import setup, find_packages
>
> ```
> setup(name='scrapy-mymodule',
>   entry_points={
>     'scrapy.commands': [
>       'my_command=my_scrapy_module.commands:MyCommand',
>     ],
>   },
>  )
> ```